# Secure SSH host keys

Tags: ssh

I am trying to fix my SSH setup on Fedora and RedHat with [ssh-audit](https://github.com/arthepsy/ssh-audit).

I managed to fix the ciphers and algorithms by setting

```
KexAlgorithms diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
Ciphers chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr
MACs hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com
```

in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

The audit tool is still complaining about the host keys that should be re-generated:

```
# host-key algorithms
[...]
(key) ecdsa-sha2-nistp256            -- [fail] using weak elliptic curves
                                     `- [warn] using weak random number generator could reveal the key
                                     `- [info] available since OpenSSH 5.7, Dropbear SSH 2013.62
[...]
# algorithm recommendations (for OpenSSH 7.9)
(rec) -ecdsa-sha2-nistp256           -- key algorithm to remove
```

I then recreated the Diffie-Hellman moduli and generated new keys

```
rm -fv /etc/ssh/ssh_host_*
ssh-keygen -G moduli-2048.candidates -b 2048
ssh-keygen -T moduli-2048 -f moduli-2048.candidates
cp moduli-2048 /etc/ssh/moduli
ssh-keygen -A
```

The audit tool is still complaining. How could I use a better random number generator? I can I exclude ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 by the key generation?

Comment: The link above points to old `ssh-audit`, the maintained fork is https://github.com/jtesta/ssh-audit, also available via `pip install ssh-audit`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sshd-keygen@service can be configured with this file:

`/lib/systemd/system/sshd-keygen.target`

By default on RHEL8 it has:

```
[Unit]
Wants=sshd-keygen@rsa.service
Wants=sshd-keygen@ecdsa.service
Wants=sshd-keygen@ed25519.service
PartOf=sshd.service
```

If @Matteo would remove the Wants for **rsa** and **ecdsa** host keys, then these files won't reappear after restarting sshd.

[ssh-audit](https://github.com/jtesta/ssh-audit) is happy if you remove from `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` the lines:

```
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
```

Answer (score 2):

All of the curves used by ECDSA keys are considered weak. Just delete the `ssh_host_ecdsa_key` and `ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub` files without replacing them, and/or comment out the entries for them in `sshd_config`. The only kinds of keys worth having are RSA and Ed25519, and you should already have them.

Comment: It works but they are regenerated each time I start the sshd service. I have to check what is happening there...

Comment: See if commenting out the entries for them makes sshd stop using them, even if they exist.

Comment: If I comment them out, they are still re-generated but not used. So fine for me :-)

Comment: Change the permission to world readable, then sshd will not use them.

Comment: @bbaassssiiee That seems unwise. The private key could get stolen, and then some unaware sysadmin could later "fix" the permissions.